# What's the SLAM method in stereo_mapping of rtabmap_ros?

Tags: slam, navigation, rtabmap-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello,

I want to  learn the stereo_mapping method  of the Rtabmap_ros in the http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap website . But I just learned that it is  a RGB-D Graph SLAM approach based on a global Bayesian loop closure detector. I want to know what's the specical mechod  of slam ,such as KF-SLAM 、PF-SLAM or Graph optimization？And are there  any  papers about that slam method?

Thank you very much for your help!!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223169/what%27s-the--slam-method-in-stereo_mapping-of-rtabmap_ros-?/) by [xiqing](https://answers.ros.org/users/24127/xiqing/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-12-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It uses graph optimization (TORO, g2o or GTSAM) to correct the map on loop closures. You can find the related papers on top of the project page: http://introlab.github.io/rtabmap/

However, there is no paper about the SLAM front-end (stereo odometry) yet :P

cheers

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2016-01-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0